# Why is possible to import namespace from sub-reference in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core-2.0, visual-studio-2019

I have 3 projects in the Solution.

- TestProject
- Child
- childOfchild

-TestProject has reference to Child project

-Child project has reference to childOfchild project

I would expect not to be able to create an instance of the class from the childOfchild project inside the TestProject. It does not make sense to me. If I want I will import childOfchild project to TestProject but I don't want that.
This is exactly what I want to avoid and I want clearly separate layers.

[image]

I am quite sure that this did not work like this earlier.
I would appreciate if someone explains me why is this case.

Comment: Isn't it because it refers a project of the same solution? at runetime we can't avoid the test project to call the child of child. But anyway  I also have a feeling this may be something I would like to avoid, at least in my VS solution when compilation happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is provided by the new project system for .NET Core/.NET Standard/SDK-based csproj (pick a name, they all mean the same).  The new behavior is that PackageReferences and ProjectReferences are now transitive by default, meaning that when you reference a project, you will automatically inherit its Package- or ProjectReferences.

You can control this on the project which contains that reference by setting the `PrivateAssets` property on that reference.  In your example: in Child.csproj, you can do this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\ChildOfChild\ChildOfChild.csproj" PrivateAssets="all" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This tells the project system "I want to reference ChildOfChild, but I don't want that implementation detail exposed to projects which reference me."

See this [blog post](https://www.erikheemskerk.nl/transitive-nuget-dependencies-net-core-got-your-back/) for more information.

Comment: Adding this: the rules about what can be referenced in an assembly (e.g. public classes) haven't changed, just how you get to them transitively...